# How to make a list with JS and save it with localStorage

Tags: javascript

### Update: I got it to work

I have the following code:

```js
function saveLocal() {
    var a = prompt("Name:");
    document.getElementById("variables").innerHTML += a + ", ";
    var p = document.getElementById("variables").value;
    localStorage.setItem("names", p);
  }
function retrieve() {
  var d = localStorage.getItem("names");
  document.getElementById("variables").value = d
}
```

```css
#variables {
  color: lime;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  border: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="saveLocal()">Save</button>
<br>
<textarea id="variables" readonly>Saved Names are: </textarea>
<button onclick="retrieve()">Retrieve Note Names</button>
```

This will prompt for a name and then add it to the textarea while saving it to a localStorage. However, after I push the retrieve button, I cannot add more variables. Or at least doesn't show. How do I fix this?

Comment: `setInterval(fn, 2)` will run the function every 2 milliseconds (actually less often, but it'll try). Probably not what you want. Why not just have a "Load" button that loads the data from localStorage?

Comment: Okay, I added that

Comment: I also changed my question

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON parse/stringify to store an array of names.

```
 function getNames(){
      names = localStorage.getItem("names") || "[]"
      return JSON.parse(names);
    }

    function saveLocal() {
      names = getNames()
    
      var a = prompt("Name:");
      if (a) {
        names.push(a)
        localStorage.setItem("names", JSON.stringify(names))
    
        retrieve()
      }
    }
    
    function retrieve() {
      names = getNames();
      document.getElementById("variables").value = "Saved Names are: " + names
    }
    
            
            retrieve()
            
            <button onclick="saveLocal()">Save</button>
            <br>
            <textarea id="variables" readonly></textarea>
            <button onclick="retrieve()">Retrieve Note Names</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

on your `saveLocal()` function, you could do this:

```js
function saveLocal() {
  var currentNames = localStorage.getItem('names')
  var updatedNames = currentNames + ', ' + a)
  localStorage.setItem('names', updatedNames)
}
```

this will get the names already stored (variable `currentNames`)  and will concatenate with the new name (your `a`). Then you just need to store the new names with `localStorage.setItem`.